# RESTful API for Todos using Hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose

My goal is to create a simple restful api that will be accessed by an AngularJS front end. Even though it's fairly simple, I'd like understand how to make it more reliable, secure, and best-practices compliant. The whole api is contained in a single file, I'm not overly concerned about organization at the moment (unless it can help with the items I've mentioned above). I'm using mongoose, hapi, and joi for validation.

## server.js

```
'use strict';

var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Good = require('good');
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Joi = require('joi');

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@proximus.modulusmongo.net:xxxx/xxxx');

var todoSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  isCompleted: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, required: true },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, required: true }
});

var Todo = Mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema, 'Todos');

var server = new Hapi.Server(3000);

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/v1/todos',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
        return;
      }

      reply(todos);
    });
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/v1/todos/{id}',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    Todo.find({ _id: request.params.id }, function(err, todo) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
        return;
      }

      reply(todo);
    });

  },
  config: {
    validate: {
      params: {
        id: Joi.string().required()
      }
    }
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'PUT',
  path: '/api/v1/todos/{id}',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    Todo.findOne({ _id: request.params.id }, function(err, todo) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
        return;
      }

      todo.title = request.payload.title;
      todo.isCompleted = request.payload.isCompleted;
      todo.updatedAt = new Date();
      todo.save();

      reply(todo);
    });
  },
  config: {
    validate: {
      params: {
        id: Joi.string().required()
      },
      payload: {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        __v: Joi.number(),
        title: Joi.string(),
        isCompleted: Joi.boolean(),
        createdAt: Joi.date(),
        updatedAt: Joi.date()
      }
    }
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/v1/todos',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    var newTodo = new Todo({
      title: request.payload.title,
      isCompleted: request.payload.isCompleted,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    });

    newTodo.save(function(err, todo) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
        return;
      }

      reply(todo);
    });
  },
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
        title: Joi.string(),
        isCompleted: Joi.boolean(),
      }
    }
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'DELETE',
  path: '/api/v1/todos/{id}',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    Todo.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id, function(err, todo) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
        return;
      }

      reply(todo);
    });
  },
  config: {
    validate: {
      params: {
        id: Joi.string().required()
      }
    }
  }
});

server.pack.register(Good, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    server.start(function() {
      server.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like your code.

- Use of `'use strict';`
- No comments, but the code is written so that they are not needed anywhere
- Good naming, good size of functions, things are in their logical place

The only thing is that I would not put uid/pwd in the source code, but use environment variables:

```
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@proximus.modulusmongo.net:xxxx/xxxx');
```

Comment: how about letting monoose validate the model, not letting the controller to get involved in validation? I think the model should be able to validate itself @konijn

Answer (score 1):

few remarks that apply even if the code is for Hapi Pre 8 version:

- I would suggest to have just one call to `route` with an array
- Structure with a plugin, so that you specify the prefix when loading `/api/v1/links`
- Eventualy extra schemas and handler into objects, that you point to in the route config.

Otherwise good, very good as @konjin said :)